# GestureListener's fling method doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I'm using `SimpleGestureDetector` from the [libgdx-users Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/SimpleDirectionGestureDetector) as my `InputProcessor`. I set it in the `created()` method:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcess(new SimpleDirectionGestureDetector(charController));
```

`charController` is my class which implements the `DirectionListener` interface defined in the `SimpleDirectionGestureDetector` class and it is responsible for moving the player character. However the character doesn't change direction when I'm performing a fling action in any direction. I've checked and the `fling()` method in the `SimpleDirectionGesture` class doesn't get called and I have no idea why, since everything seems good. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the users wiki is outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/GestureDetectorTest.java) will help you. If not - let me know, maybe I will make small test app for you.